# Does update-function-configuration reload Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

What happens with Lambda functions already running when we run the command `update-function-configuration`?

Is a new Lambda function triggered with the new configuration? Or only the new Lambda functions get the new configuration?

Comment: Next time your Lambda is invoked, it will run with the new config settings. It will involve a cold start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All subsequent invocations after updating the configuration will use a new container which can be seen by the new log group stream created. Each container has its own log stream.